# Combined audio and video as video file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, video, video-processing, matlab-cvst

I want to combine audio and video as video file in MATLAB. I have wrote following code:
But it gives me error !?! can anyone guide me ?

```
[filename pathname]=uigetfile({'*.*'},'Video Selector');
fulpathname=strcat(pathname,filename);
videoFReader = vision.VideoFileReader(fulpathname);
[AUDIO,Fs] = audioread(fulpathname);
videoFWriter = vision.VideoFileWriter('myFile.avi','FrameRate',videoFReader.info.VideoFrameRate);

for i=1:50
videoFrame = step(videoFReader);
step(videoFWriter, videoFrame,AUDIO);
end

release(videoFReader);
release(videoFWriter);
```

Comment: Which error? (You seem to be reading the audio into "y" and then not doing anything with it - where does "AUDIO" come from?)

Comment: I am sorry for this mistake. AUDIO is audio file which needs to combined with video. Here I just want to know how combined audio and video in MATLAB.

Comment: @amir: what is the error exactly?

Comment: @MohammadIzady Error using vision.VideoFileWriter/step
Too many input arguments; expected 1 (in addition to the object handle), got 2.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write both audio and video using vision.VideoFileWriter you should set AudioInputPort option to true. This is by default false and the object expects only video data input. If you set to true, then you can send both video and audio as inputs to step method.

Answer (score 2):

Example for writing both audio and video

```
% It is assumed that audio is stored in "data" variable

% Idea is simple: Just divide length of the audio sample by the number of frames to be written in the video frames. ( it is equivalent to saying that what audio you   % want to have with that particular frame)

% First make AudioInputPort property true (by default this is false)

writerObj = vision.VideoFileWriter('Guitar.avi','AudioInputPort',true);

% total number of frames
nFrames   = 250;

% assign FrameRate (by default it is 30)

writerObj.FrameRate =  20;

% length of the audio to be put per frame

val = size(data,1)/nFrames;

% Read one frame at a time

for k = sf : nFrames
    % reading frames from a directory
    Frame=(imread(strcat('frame',num2str(k),'.jpg')));
    % adding the audio variable in the step function
    step(writerObj,Frame,data(val*(k-1)+1:val*k,:)); % it is 2 channel that is why I have put (:)

end

% release the video

release(writerObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

use 'videoFReader.SampleRate' instead of "videoFReader.info.VideoFrameRate" the error will be removed

Comment: Why? What's the mistake he made?

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Navan answered you have to add in the AudioInputPort to ture first. Your videoFrame has to be a structure of Frames. The audio must also be a structure of the same length as the Number of Video frames. Your audio sampling rate will be obviously more than the number of frames. 
For this i suggest you to divide the number of audio samples by the frame rate and round off the value. 
These steps works for me.

Comment: Adding a practical example always helps in these cases.